# The Wronskian are the same that det $\Phi$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, determinant

I need to show that for a scalar equation:
$$a_0(t)y^{(n)}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+a_n(t)y=0 $$
where $a_0,a_1,...,a_n$ are continuous on I, and $a_0(t)\neq0$, $\det\Phi$ is the same that the Wronskian, i proved that the wronskian satisfy the Abel's identity (is sufficient?), and i proved this for $n=2$, but i don't have idea how to generalizate, thanks for the help.